# Change img src to direct link, for use in photo gallary

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents, src

I'm trying to make a page that will accept a URL input by the user then it will display all the images from that address. I have this working, however if the image src on the page is written like this:

```
/image/picture.jpg
```

Rather than this:

```
http://www.site.com/image/picture.jpg
```

Then my page wont display it because its not local to my server. What I want to know, is there a simple way to directly link to that files location?

My Code is below:

```
<?php 
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.deviantart.com/');

$dom = new domDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$images = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $data = $image->getAttribute('src');
  echo "<img src='".$data."' />";
}
?>
```

Comment: **hotlinking, leeching, piggy-backing, direct linking, offsite image grabs, bandwidth theft** is evil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prepend site url to src element. I would aslo add check, if src starts with http://

```
foreach ($images as $image) {
  $data = $image->getAttribute('src');
  if (!preg_match('/https?:\/\//i', $data)) {
    // If src attribute does not start with "http://" or "https://", then prepend site base url
    $data = 'http://site.com/' . ltrim($data, '/');
  }
  echo "<img src='".$data."' />";
}
```